# No reply after declining a PhD offer

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, email

Couple of weeks ago, several professors from one of the universities I received an offer from wrote me asking if they could help me with anything (to decide on a place I choose). As pleasant as it was, I wrote (what I think was) a very nice email declining that PhD offer to each one of them. It's been quite a while now, but none of them have replied, while from other places I've received wishes of good luck. Have I burned some bridges there?

Comment: Definitely overthinking this one a bit.

Comment: Why do you think a reply was necessary. They offered, you said no, that is the end of it.

Comment: @JonCuster it's just a bit odd to me, one day I receive 3 emails from the same uni, and then none of them replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably no burned bridges. Like everyone else (especially now) they are busy and just focused on the essential things they need to do to keep everything else together. In normal times you might have gotten a few more replies, but not from everyone. They just say to themselves "oh well" and move on to the next crisis.

I suspect that even those who haven't replied hope you succeed. When one does, we all do.

Comment: It's difficult to guess how do you have a reasonable explanation for almost all kinds of questions... :D Thank you.. Salutes..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, thanks for your confidence. It is just that I'm old and was an educator since the late pleistocene and I tried to learn along the way. I've seen a lot and have been in good situations and bad. I even once had a student with your family name. That was a good situation, of course.

Comment: :) That is nice to know :) Thanks again.